# Cant access sub projects header files in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

[image]I created a single view application project.Into that project I added library project as sub project.But inside the classes of main project I am not able import Subprojects files.Getting file not found error.I tried many paths in place of header path field but none of them works.Please help ...[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you linked the library within the Build Phases tab?

Comment: Yes I have linked the library..

Comment: Could you provide screenshot of the full exception, import as well as the linked library?

Comment: @mservidio:Please check the screenshot of exception

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/41377/creating-a-static-library-in-ios-tutorial

Comment: Actually That error is not because of problem with the creation of static library..

Comment: @KiritVaghela:Please check the new screen shot there also I am getting file not found error..

Comment: @haritha Create a header file and import your classes to that file and use that header file in other project

Comment: @KiritVaghela:Inside which project should I create the header file

Comment: @KiritVaghela:Actually what is the difference in creating a new header with all imported headers and directly calling the headers.

Comment: and add path of that header file in Search Header Path in your project Build Settings